# discord.js problem: How can I implement a command that will only allow people with the kick and administrator permission to use the command

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, discord.js

I used this command for kicks, but everyone in the server can now kick. I just want to add something that will only allow people with the admin and kick permissions to use it.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`error. solution; please specify one person to kick, maybe that person has higher permissions than me and you`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement something like

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") && 
!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return mesage.channel.send("You don't 
have permission to kick a member");
```

at the beginning of your kick command code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command, listener, inhibitor+ framework [discord akairo](https://discord-akairo.github.io/) (extension of discord.js) you can easily do this with both user and client permissions.

```js
export default class Test extends Command {
    constructor() {
        super('test', {
            aliases: ['test'],
            userPermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR']
            clientPermissions: ['BAN_MEMBERS']
        })
    }

    async exec(message: Message) {
        message.reply('Hello World')
    }
}
```

Pretty useful for building large networks of commands.